# Multithreading slower than single threading

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance

I writing a program that does heavy calculations for large arrays in real-time. The task can be split into several sub-arrays for multithreading. However, I cannot run this any faster using threads.

Here is a sample dummy code which was created for demonstration (same problem).
Two threads-version ends up lasting 39 seconds, which is couple of seconds longer if they were computed one after another(!). It doesn't matter if the arrays are global etc. I also tested using "thread constructors" only once, but with the same result.

I'm using XCode (5.1.1) and Macbook Air (2013 model, Core i5, Os X 10.8.5). Yes, this is old computer, I'm rarely programming...

So, could you find any mistake in the logic I have in the code or could it be somewhere in the settings of Xcode etc?

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

class Value
{
public:
    float a[3000000];
};

void cycle(Value *val)
{
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<3000000; i++)
        {
            val->a[i]=n;
            n+=0.0001;
        }
}

int main()
{
    Value *val1=new Value, *val2=new Value;
   
    clock_t start,stop;
   
    start=clock();
    for (int i=0; i<1000; i++)
    {
        thread first (cycle,val1);
        thread second (cycle,val2);
        first.join();
        second.join();
    }
   
    stop=clock();
    float tdiff=(((float)stop - (float)start) / 1000000.0F);
    std::cout<<endl<<"This took "<<tdiff<<" seconds...";
    return 0;
}
'''
```

Comment: How do you compile this? Did you tun on optimizations? And how does the single-threaded code look? Please show [mre], there are many subtleties to meassuring performances, especially when dealing with multi-threading.

Comment: There is no `n` declared anywhere. Please post code that you have compiled and run.

Comment: If the `n` that is not included here is a global variable, then it makes sense you are not getting a speed up.  Shared global state can make your code run basically in serial mode, but even worse.

Comment: there is a joke that goes something like this: "One programmer needs 1 day to finsish a program, how many days do 10 programmers need for the same? - 10 days." You are spwaning and immediately joining the threads in the loop which makes your code heavily sequential.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 why not post this as an answer?

Comment: @SergeyA let me try....

Comment: `a` is never used, so the compiler probably just removed the whole thing. Your timing is probably worthless.

Comment: @churill you may be right, apparently its a stripped down example to measure something. I was teased to write an answer, otherwise I would have insisted for clarification ;). Nevertheless this spawning and joining threads is most likely biggest part of the difference OP sees compared to the sequential version

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 Yes, after reading your answer I agree that this causes more overhead than I initially thought. (Removed now outdated comment)

Comment: @molbdnilo how about making that an answer. I don't feel like throwing away my answer, just because it missed the point ;), but it would be better to have the actual answer as well.

Comment: Include code that actually builds and runs.  Include compiler flags.  Include actual timing information.

Answer (score 5):

There is a joke that goes something like that:

> One programmer needs 1 day to finsish a program, how many days do 10 programmers need for the same? - 10 days.

The work in your code is done in this loop:

> ```
> for (int i=0; i<1000; i++)
> {
>     thread first (cycle,val1);
>     thread second (cycle,val2);
>     first.join();
>     second.join();
> }
> ```

Now consider that spawning and joining threads is overhead. In total your parallel code does more than a sequential would have to do, in gerenal there is no way around that. And you are not creating and joining threads once, but `1000`-times, ie you add `1000`-times overhead.

Don't expect code to run faster by simply adding more threads to it. I refer you to [Amdahl's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law) or  [Gustavson's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gustafson%27s_law) (which basically states the same just a bit more positive).

I suggest you to experiment with sequential vs threaded but only one thread to get a feeling for the overhead. You can compare this:

```
for (int i=0; i<1000; i++)
{
    thread first (cycle,val1);
    first.join();
}
```

With a sequential version that does not use any threads. You will be surprised by the difference.

You get most out of multithreading when the threads do lots of work (cf Amdahl/Gustavson) and when there is no synchronisation between different threads. Your `1000` times joining the threads is basically a barrier, where `second` has to wait doing nothing until `first` is finished. Such barriers are best avoided.

Last but not least, as mentioned in a comment, your benchmark is rather questionable, because you are not using the result of the computations. That is, either you didn't turn on optimizations which makes the results rather meaningless, or you did turn on optimizations and the compiler might optimize things away without you noticing it. And actually I am not sure whether you are comparing two versions that do the same work, or if perhaps your parallel version is doing twice the work. Moreover, when measuring time you need to take care to measure wall clock time not cpu time, because cpu time adds times spend on multiple cores, while you want to compare wall clock time.

**TL;DR**: More threads != automatically less runtime.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I admit I presented in this a bit badly. The 1000 times repetition was demonstrating performance in real-time calculations. It could be use to get frames per second (FPS). Anyway, now it works! The killing element was "clock" function that showed time incorrectly. Now the speed is 100% faster as it should be using two threads.

Comment: @BearProductions sorry but "Now the speed is 100% faster as it should be using two threads" sounds like you ignored all what I wrote in the answer :(. Using two threads instead of one *should* not be twice as fast. I somehow missed the actual issue, but nevertheless what I wrote does apply.

Answer (score 1):

If you read the documentation for `clock`, you might notice that it says that time can appear to go faster if the process executes on multiple cores; `clock` is a total CPU-use approximation, not "wall clock time", and one "CPU tick" on two cores in parallel is the same amount of "time" as two sequential "ticks" on one core.
(By the way: in order to get the time in seconds, you should be dividing by `CLOCKS_PER_SEC`.)

Using a more appropriate timer, like `std::chrono::steady_clock`, will show that the sequential variant takes almost twice as long as the multithreaded version.
The difference can be explained completely by the overhead of creating and destroying threads.

Comment: `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock` is not necessary a monotonic clock and so not well suited to measure timings too. `std::chrono::steady_clock` is.

Comment: Thanks molbdnilo! That really solved the problem. Changing to "std::chrno::high_resolution_clock" revealed the true time spend in calculations. The "clock" is showing time incorrectly. Now the code is actually 130% faster when using three threats.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike the other comments suggest, `n` is not the culprit, neither is the sequential joins.
Each thread performs the same operation `cycle`, so how could there be any improvement?
You have to manually split the workload between the two threads, so that each one works on half the data.